# How to echo something in C# in an .aspx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know you can do this

```
<%= Request.Form[0] %>
```

But how do you do something like this?

```
<% if(Request.Form[0]!=null)
     echo "abc";
%>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<% if(Request.Form[0]!=null)
    Response.Write("abc");
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to show the form value unless it doesn't exist then show "abc"?

```
<%= Request.Form[0] ?? "abc" %>
```

Or you could can use if blocks and normal markup inside.

```
<% if(Request.Form[0]!=null) { %>

   <div class="echo">abc</div>

<% } %>
```